# How can I add 1 to a floating point number in unsigned int, using bitwise operations?

Tags: c

I am trying to implement my own floor function using bitwise operations. I have it working for positive numbers, so I get

```
 roundDown(5.4) = 5.
```

I want to round down for negative numbers too. For example, I want

```
roundDown(-5.4)= -6
```

My strategy is to take the negative number, clear the signed bit to make it positive, add 1, round down as I do for positive numbers, and then set the signed bit back to 1 to make the number negative again.

My problem is that I don't know how to add 1 to the unsigned int. I want to use bitwise operations to do this, I've been at it for hours and would really like to figure this out.

Comment: Possible, but it's going to be painful - you need to check the exponent part before doing any thing on the mantissa. Just do the thing normally.

Comment: Hm, why not just `int roundDown(float x) { return x > 0 ? (int)x :  (int)(-x + 1); }`?

Comment: I need to do this without casting, it's supposed to be possible using only bit operations. Thanks though!

Comment: Perhaps the last one would be (int)(x-1)?

Comment: @nhahtdh, what should I check the exponent for? And how should I change the mantissa? Please explain :)

Comment: @user2057841: Are you working in an environment without the floating point unit? And what is the format of the floating point? IEEE single/double precision? OR your own format?

Comment: I'm working only with unsigned ints. My function takes a float to round and casts it to unsigned int. Then I do all my operations on that, and convert back to float.

Comment: If you have implemented your own `floor` function already, it shouldn't be too hard to implement a `ceil` function (round up) for positive numbers. Then you can return `-ceil(-negative_number)` to round down negative numbers.

Comment: Actually, I think that's already what I'm trying to do. I can't figure out how to implement the ceil function because it requires adding 1 to the floating point number in the unsigned short.

Comment: @nhahtdh, to do the math I am looking at IEEE floats. Specifically like the ones in this converter: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: This seems to be good resource to read on how addition works: https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~jjohnson/2012-13/fall/cs281/lectures/pdf/cs281_lec14.pdf

Comment: Bring back the [homework] tag! :P

Comment: The only reason for doing this would be mental mastu... er, your own curiosity.  It can be done, but you must extract the exponent and figure out where it implies the binary point it, then do the increment and handle possible overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have roundDown() working for positive numbers, use it for negative numbers.

```
double roundDownAll(double x) {
  if (x >= 0.0) {
    return roundDown(x);
  }
  else {
    double y;
    y = -roundDown(-x);
    // If no rounding occurred (e.g. -5 == -roundDown(- -5);
    if (x == y) {
      // We are done.
      return y;
      }
    else {
      // rounding occurred in the wrong direction, so compensate.
      return y-1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is increment implemented with bit operations.  Unsigned int would be better than int.

```
int bitincr(int a)
{
    int b = 1;
    do
    {
        int c = a & b;
        a = a ^ b;
        b = c << 1;
    } 
    while (b != 0);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/03/nearbyintf2) shows how to round a positive `float` to the nearest integer with only bit operations on the representation. Rounding down, for both positive and negative numbers, involve similar operations (when rounding a positive float to the nearest integer, sometimes, one needs to round up). Key steps are extracting the exponent:

```
int exp = ((u>>23) & 255) - 127;
```

Computing what bit should be set in a representation of a floating number `1.0` aligned with the input:

```
if (23 - exp < 0) return f;
unsigned int one = 1U << (23 - exp);
```

And using `one` as reference to understand how the bits of the significant should be changed:

```
unsigned int mask = one - 1;
unsigned int frac = u & mask;
...
```